# Why jQuery hover gets stuck sometimes and how to fix it?

Tags: jquery, hover

Sometimes when I hover on the elements the dropdown sucks and works vice versa, mostly when I'm already on the element and when the page starts to load, so you should test it with some reloads.

**Check out : [Live Preview](http://jsbin.com/odama3/5)**

**Video Screencast : [Video Screencast Link](http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c66fYYQuG)**

**The jQuery:**

```
  $(function() {
    $("ul > li").hover(function() {
      $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
    }, function() {
      $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
    });
  });
```

This snippet finds all `ul`'s and fades in or out the `ul`'s what inside of the `parent ul`.

Comment: Firefox 3.6 and latest Chrome, and IE 8 and latest Opera, I tested on windows 7 and mac leopard too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine.  There is an appearance of the drop down getting stuck if you move your mouse horizontally.  This is because the width of the li tag spans the whole window.  Maybe you just need to set a shorter width.

Comment: The live preview is just a short demo, I use this jQuery in my own project too where the width is specified and I still have the problem.

Comment: I see.  Well I can't reproduce the behavior you are describing.  Can you provide a more complete demo?  Or steps to reproduce?